bash globbing doesn't generate non-existent filepaths when using { .. } with *
I want to check the existence of some files in our vast filesystem hierarchy. I thought I could use globbing with ls -al for this.
The files are always stored in the form <name>/2024/10/<name>_20241001.ext. So what I did was first to use a glob within the folder <name>/2024/10/nameX_202410{01..30} and this turned up some files that weren't existing:
~/nameX/2024/10 $ ls -al nameX_202410{01..30}.ext
ls: cannot access 'nameX_20241001.ext': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'nameX_20241002.ext': No such file or directory
...

Now I tried to apply the same pattern to all of our  folders:
~ $ ls -al */2024/10/*202410{01..30}.mbts
-rw-r--r-- 1 process process 99757768 Nov  3 03:51  nameX/2024/10/nameX_20241026.ext
-rw-r--r-- 1 process process 99757768 Nov  4 03:52  nameX/2024/10/nameX_20241027.ext
-rw-r--r-- 1 process process 99757768 Oct  9 03:52  nameY/2024/10/nameY_20241001.ext
-rw-r--r-- 1 process process 99757768 Oct 10 03:52 nameY/2024/10/nameY_20241002.ext

But this only ever shows the files that are existing, so not the ones that are missing. So there's not a single "No such file or directory" option. What is happening and can I circumvent this globbing behaviour somehow?

Enable nullglob, shopt -s nullglob, then try ls -al */2024/10/*202410[0-3][0-9].ext

The manual states:

The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

This means that the command line argument
*/2024/10/*202410{01..30}.mbts

is first turned into the words
*/2024/10/*20241001.mbts
*/2024/10/*20241002.mbts
...
*/2024/10/*20241029.mbts
*/2024/10/*20241030.mbts

by brace expansion.
Only now pathname expansion occurs (pattern matching of the wildcards *). This produces only names of files that exist.
This means, what you want to achieve is not possible with this command line argument.

... unless none of the files exist at all?

@StefanHegny Yes, but that does not seem to be the case in the given example (and I don't want to complicate the answer).

You can try a loop instead:
for i in *
do
    [ -d "$i" ] && ls -la "${i}"/2024/10/"${i}"_202410{01..30}.mbts
done

Since this no longer involves any wildcards, the inner expansion will obtain all file names, including those that don’t exist.

You could make it for i in */ and not need the test -d check.

Yes, but then I'd need ${i%/} to get rid of the trailing slash. OK, but slightly annoying.

There is no globbing in nameX_202410{01..30}.ext. Globbing happens only if you use at least one of the specific globbing characters (*, ? and so on; see filename expansion in the man-page).
You only use brace expansion in your excample. You could loop over the expanded value and skip non-existent files:
for f in nameX_202410{01..30}.ext
do
  [[ -e $f ]] && ls -l $f
done



The files are always stored in the form <name>/2024/10/<name>_20241001.ext.

Problem solved.
$ find
.
./bar
./bar/1
./bar/2
./baz
./baz/2
./baz/3
./foo
./foo/1
./foo/2
./foo/3

$ for d in */; do ls -l "$d"/{1..3}; done >/dev/null
ls: cannot access 'bar/3': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'baz/1': No such file or directory

Since you have the list of directory names, it is trivial to explicitly construct the list of filenames that should be there and try to access them. Throw away stdout and your stderr is the list you wanted.
If you just want a simple report of the missing files -
$ for d in *; do for f in $d/{1..3}; do [[ -e "$f" ]] || missing+=("$f"); done; done

$ (( ${#missing} )) && printf "%s\n" "Missing Files:" "${missing[@]}"
Missing Files:
bar/3
baz/1

